# Paramiko only connects to IP address not hostname in Python?

Tags: python, paramiko

I have function like this in python:

```
def test_ssh(host, username, password):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
```

Problem is:
`test_ssh('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'hello')` works

But `test_ssh('localhost', 'root', 'hello')` doesn't work

Error I get is:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost: Name or service not known
```

What's causing this? Thanks

Comment: DNS resolution of HOSTNAME is not providing proper IP

Comment: Edit " ** /etc/hosts ** " file, put in the IP and Hostname in this file. That ought to resolve your Hostname and IP

Comment: Edit /etc/hosts
Add like (example) - 
#IP  hostname [[alias1] [...]]
127.0.0.1  localhost
172.22.0.1  mymachine.home mymachine

Comment: Lastly an awesome link - http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch18_:_Configuring_DNS#Introduction_to_DNS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my comments werent making much sense (putting them all together) (assuming your OS is Linux) -

Reason for your error -

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost: Name or service not known

Is - DNS resolution of HOSTNAME is not providing proper IP (comment#1)

Test with this command (terminal)-

> **host** *localhost*

What you can try -

Edit  **/etc/hosts**  file, put in the IP and Hostname in this file. That ought to resolve your Hostname and IP 
Like This -

> #IP  hostname [[alias1] [...]] 
>   127.0.0.1    localhost 
>   172.22.0.9  mymachine.home mymachine

Lastly an awesome link - http://bit.ly/IHhA1R

*EDIT*

Possible workflow -

- User Registers, enters **HOSTNAME**
- We run command (with python we can use os.subprocess or os.popen) -

> **bash$** dig *HOSTNAME*

- Fetch the IP of the HOSTNAME
- Try Connection to HOST with IP instead of the HOSTNAME

Always use the same workflow to get Latest IP of the HOSTNAME provided by the user, connect using IP instead of HOSTNAME

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to build a dynamic application. Each time user put their hostname, I can't open the file /etc/hosts and add their corresponding IP and hostname.

Comment: True - 
Tell me what does the following commands print for you - 
Command 1 - host <HOSTNAME>
Command 2 - nslookup <HOSTNAME>

Comment: host host_name gives the hostname and other one gives the server and adress info.

Comment: @user1881957 - check the latest edit in the answer, that might work.

Comment: This takes alot of parsing. Instead we can use just host hostname and get the IP address.

Comment: Anyway. Thanks for coming with the beautiful ideas.

Answer (score 0):

try giving `ssh.connect(hostname=host, username=username, password=password)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually this can even not work when host can be resolved.

First try:

```
import socket
socket.getaddrinfo('google.com', None)
socket.getaddrinfo('localhost', None)
```

If google.com returns tuple with address and localhost also returns correctly - then your system setup is correct. I do not know why but I had this issue and passing `socket.getaddrinfo(host, None)[0][1][4]` worked.